Can Desuetude apply to the US Constitution?
Desuetude in my understanding means null and void through obsolescence.
What I wonder is if an American constitutional provision could fall into total oblivion, only to be revived, or is there a doctrine protecting us from de facto obsolete laws.
There are strong arguments in my mind for either some desuetude or no desuetude. Namely the interest of giving historic legitimacy to the Constitution, or the interest of giving stability to our practical frame of government. If one interprets the Constitution legalistically, you can quibble away much of current law. If you opt for the spirit of the laws, you will see some portions of law code go into disuse never to rise again.
An example might be the "Constitutional option" versions of unitary executive theory vs civil service reform. Clearly the spoils system is more historical, hence the creation of civil service reform law in later history lending stability to the federal administrative state. The implications reach to the core of Presidential and Congressional powers over de facto policy.
I am aware amendments can fill the really huge gaps, but why should the onus be on the ones accustomed to current practice, but not protected by the current written constitution?

Welcome to Politics.SE! Can you clarify what exactly your question is? Are you asking whether there's a mechanism in the US Constitution that allows obsolete laws to be annulled?

This question would be far better if you clarified what you are asking about, preferably with a question mark (you are supposed to be asking a question here), if you made your post less abstruse, and preferably if you did so with an example. For example, are you asking about anti-abortion advocates who want to reinvigorate the mostly moribund Comstock Act?

The principle for interpreting the constitution in a changing context is the Supreme Court.
There are several elements in the Constitution which are irrelevant to a 21st century context.  For example "Indians not taxed" is irrelevant, and Native American people all "count" in apportion of seats in Congress. It is reasonable to say that this element of the Constitution has become subject to Desuetude. What would happen if (for some reason) the federal government decided not to tax nor count some Native American people?  Who knows, it would be up to SCOTUS to sort it out (and would doubtless become a party political matter). It would be quite reasonable for a future SCOTUS to rule that this element of the Constitution is now de facto obsolete, and attempts to use it for personal or party gain are not legal.
Similarly the matter of "quartering troops" has no real relevance in the modern era. The words remain in the Constitution, but it seems unlikely that the protection it gives will be required.
There isn't a way of interpreting the Constitution that all agree on.  There are "Textualists", "Originalists", "Living Constitution-ists"  and other schools of thought. Their approach in deciding if a given element of the Constitution applies in a modern context, or if it has become obsolete.
So, there is no principle of Desuetude in the Constitution, but the Supreme Court is the proper place for Constitutional interpretation in the modern context.

As yet another example, for some reason, the US Constitution does not mention the US Air Force or the US Space Force. An extremely strict originalist POV would deem the USAF and the USSF to be unconstitutional because while the constitution does indeed mention the US Army and US Navy in multiple places, it does not mention the USAF or the USSF. No sane person takes this extreme of an originalist interpretation.

Not sure about the quartering of troops having no relevance as there was a court case regarding that in 1982 and based on what happened it could become important again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engblom_v._Carey

"For example "Indians not taxed" is irrelevant, and Native American people all "count" in apportion of seats in Congress." This is due to 1924 legislation and not any change in constitutional law.

@JoeW The fact that the appeals court said the 3rd did apply, and the district court then dismissed (again) because of qualified immunity is especially glaring. "They didn't know it was illegal" to violate the constitution just because courts hadn't ruled on it yet, and therefore they get a pass?  What a vile principle.

@ohwilleke  Indeed, but I'm suggesting that if the 1924 law were repealed, then it would be rational for the supreme court to rule that tax and apportion still applied to native Americans because the context of the Constitution has changed since 1924. I can't say for certain that this is how the court would interpret the line but it would be reasonable for the court to assume that Native Americans should be treated fairly (even though the Constituion doesn't  explicitly require this)

@JamesK I think that analysis is unlikely to be hold.

The intended mechanism for altering the US Constitution is spelled out in Article V, as your question acknowledges. When the 18th Amendment fell out of favor, it was explicitly repealed by the 21st Amendment - there was no argument that the amendment should simply be ignored as if it had not happened. There is no recognized principle or process of desuetude as applied to the US Constitution, nor to federal statutes as enacted by Congress, unless the statute contains an explicit sunset provision. Sunset provisions are the standard mechanism for ensuring that old laws do not remain on the books indefinitely, especially in the context of federal statutes.
There are two sunset provisions in the US Constitution, which both took effect in 1808, and which can be summarized as follows:

Before 1808, Congress could not ban the importation of slaves, nor amend the Constitution to allow for such a ban. The slave trade was in fact banned on January 1, 1808, the earliest date permitted.
Before 1808, Congress could not have enacted the Sixteenth Amendment or any similar amendment, but it took over a century (and a rather controversial Supreme Court case) for Congress to get around to doing that.


Why would the sixteenth amendment have been impossible before 1808?

@phoog The Constitution has two sunset clauses in it. Article 1 section 9 clause 1 was with regard to laws regarding slavery prior to Jan 1 1808.  Article 5 says in part that "no Amendment which may be made prior to the Year One thousand eight hundred and eight shall in any Manner affect the first and fourth Clauses in the Ninth Section of the first Article". Article 1 section 9 clause 4 stated that direct federal taxes must be apportioned by state populations. This means the 16th amendment was impossible prior to 1808. In fact, the 16th explicitly overturned article 1 section 9 clause 4.

As a side note, the 13th and 14th amendments would also have been impossible to enact prior to January 1, 1808.

@DavidHammen thanks.  I believe my confusion stemmed from the fact that (grammatically speaking, at least) it's really one sunset clause with a plural direct object ("the first and fourth clauses") and, as you might imagine, I'd never paid much attention to the inclusion of the fourth clause.

@phoog: There are two textually separate sunset provisions, but they are not divided up in the way my answer presents. The one in Article I concerns only the slave trade, and its expiration caused the ban to become possible immediately (without an amendment). The one in Article V concerns both the slave trade and direct taxes, and its expiration enabled the Sixteenth Amendment. I did not mention the Thirteenth and Fourteenth Amendments, because the relevant portion of Article I was sunset in 1808 automatically, and did not need to be amended out.

The original function of "desuetude" arose in the context of the common law, where the law was whatever the judges (and ultimately the King) said it was.
In principle though, if they weren't actively trying to impose a new regime, they were supposed to discern the accepted laws or principles that were popularly known to exist, and arrive at a judgement in correspondence with the popular notion.
When faced with new problems, there was the somewhat legally-fictitious concept of "discovering" the laws. More accurately regarded as the judge making the law up, but doing so in a way that people would ultimately consider reasonable, by either extending an existing principle, or proposing a new design for the law if the problem (in nature or degree) seemed new.
Desuetude is the counterpart to this process, where the long absence of enforcement against an ancient problem, indicated that the law had moved on and people didn't really think the alleged wrongdoing should be considered wrong or against the law anymore.
Also, when the law was largely reproduced verbally, the risk of obsolete laws being resurrected was less, since they would simply be forgotten. The risk grew when more material started to be written down, where people could see that the law had been, and therefore things that nobody would personally remember could nevertheless be raked up from written articles. That's where the importance of desuetude as an explicit concept comes in, as a kind of judicially-declared forgetting.
Later, with the emergence of more statutory law and, especially, a parliament who assumed the overall lawmaking powers, there's more emphasis on judges following what lawmakers declare and letting the lawmakers do their own housekeeping explicitly.
It's very unlikely that American judges would recognise the outright desuetude of a constitutional provision. They might try to interpret the problem away, but if they can't muster the credibility in doing so, they would defer back to the lawmakers to fix the law.
The constitution itself is a widely publicised, well-reproduced document, and therefore the chance of a constitutional provision being utterly forgotten by American society (rather than merely left unattended, or the implications not appreciated), seems quite impossible.

The constitution also doesn't really have many detailed provisions that are likely to become obsolete. It's mostly a general roadmap for how the three branches of the federal government works. When you hear about silly, obsolete laws, they're always statutory -- lots of stuff related to horse traffic, clothing styles, or individual activities.

@Barmar, agreed. The problem it seems is that you can solve every problem with more written law, except the problem of too much written law. I think it was in the 19th century when things came to a head where centuries of accumulation, together with significant social and political change, produced a situation where even the judiciary was unable to reproduce its own understanding of what the written law was. It's what produced, at least in Britain, many codifying, consolidating, and repeal acts.

While in the US it just produces lots of fodder for comedy.
